# How to disable mouse function for a RS232 usb device in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, rs232

I have this RS232 USB device that Windows 7 thinks its a mouse. When it's activated the mouse cursor starts to jump to random places on the screen. I want to use this device but I want to disable this strange behavior.

Comment: what is this device ? is it RS232 or USB ? and how did u installed it ?

Comment: @Revolter This is a USB device that receives data that can be read from Hyperterminal (TeraTerm in my case). It is RS232 in the sense that the data is originated from a RS232 to USB conversor.

Comment: @Revolter I did not installed any software related to it. It simply works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disable-device-windows-7.htm).

Comment: Yeah, it is listed twice in the device manager, I had to disable the mouse entry as I explained here: http://hourlyapps.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-prevent-serial-to-usb-devices.html